# remove desired elements directly from body tag which are not wrapped by another parent html element

Tags: javascript, html

I am just experementing if it is possible to remove desired elements which are not wrapped by another element and which I can access via the `getElementById()` method. Here I putted two paragraph tags and a button. I attached an `onclick` event which is supposed to remove the paragraph elements, but they are not removed altogether. It removes them one by one, I mean i have to click the button two times to remove all the two paragraph tags. How to solve this problem?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>ddd</p>
<p>fff</p>
<input type='button' value='remove all elements' onClick="removeall()">
<script>
function removeall(){
  var para=document.getElementsByTagName('P');
  alert(para.length);
  for(i=0;i<para.length;i++){
     document.body.removeChild(para[i]);
  }

}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: A lot of bad practices in this code. Anyway, what does that `alert` shows you?

Comment: it shows number of paragraph elements .i have added a fiddle to the post

Comment: obviously it doesn't work. you are removing the first one...then the second one isn't the one you think it is anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the length of the array (which actually is not an array, but a live collection) will decrease every time you remove an element from it. So you will actually remove half of the `<p>` elements with that `for` loop. You might use a `while` loop instead and remove the first element of the array until the array is empty.

This is the right code:

```
function removeall() {
    var para = document.getElementsByTagName('P');

    while(para.length) para[0].parentNode.removeChild(para[0]);
}
```

The above code will remove **all** the `<p>` elements in the document.

---

In your code you used `document.body.removeChild(...)` which works fine, but is not really good because if some `<p>` element is inside another element (not directly inside `<body>`) it will not be removed and it will cause an error.

So if you only want to remove the `<p>` elements from the body you will do:

```
function removeall_frombody() {
    var para = document.querySelectorAll('body > p');

    while(para.length) document.body.removeChild(para[0]);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, since it's the most simple. it deletes all elements in `para` array until none left.

Comment: thanks a lot.i have a question.can it remove dynamically created paragraph element,i mean elements created by document.createElement('p') method??

Comment: To do this you have to store the old elements in an array and then when you want to remove the added elements you will check if they are in the array of the old elements, and, if not, remove them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `para` is a *live* collection. So, when you remove the first paragraph, `para` changes and becomes a collection of just one element, terminating the `for` loop because `para.length` becomes 1.

To avoid this, convert the collection to an array:

```
function removeall(){
   var para = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('P'));
   for(var i = 0; i < para.length; i++){
      document.body.removeChild(para[i]);
   }
}
```

Or iterate from the end instead:

```
for (var i = para.length; i--;)
    document.body.removeChild(para[i]);
```

Others suggest to use a `while` loop: it's fine too.